# Screen reading / mouse clicking under Linux / X Window System?

Tags: java, c, linux, x11

I'm learning about AI and (just for fun and practice, not profit or anything evil) I'd like to write a little bot to play a rinky-dink Flash game for me.

As a Microsoft hater, I'm embarrassed to say that I know and have used the required function calls some time ago under Windows, programming in Delphi. But these days I try to do everything under Linux and I don't seem to have any idea.

Requirements:

- to grab part of the screen's contents in image or bitmap form, periodically or on programmatic request;
- to simulate mouse pointer moves and left clicks under programmatic control;
- keyboard grabbing might come in handy too.

Ideally, I'd like to do this from a Clojure application running in the JVM, so a Java compatible library would be the cat's meow. But failing that, I could write myself a C program to mediate between X Window and my app via local TCP/IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always rely upon the good old [java.awt.Robot](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, which, i think, has all the features you're asking :

- moving mouse
- capturing a Rectangle on screen
- clicking mouse

Comment: Oh wow, I used to think that class was only suitable for testing Java programs. But the javadoc can be interpreted to mean it will work with any program. I'll have a look and report back, thanks!

Comment: It works for any program. The greatest (in the sense the most fashionable of that term) use of Robot is that applciation generating mouse track for day-long time periods : http://www.flickr.com/photos/anatoliy_zenkov/sets/72157623274370724/

Comment: And right you are. With just 17 lines of code, my program grabs a screenshot and can find and press the "start" button. The rest might be a little more work, but thanks to you I'm well on my way.